# Deserializing empty XML tags in C# with enumerations

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I've tried to achieve the deserialization as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250656/deserializing-enums) with no success:

(* I'm using LinqPad to test this, that's why you can see the .Dump() call at the end of my sample)

In this code, I'm getting "Instance validation error: '' is not a valid value for claves_sexo", because it is empty:

```
void Main()
{
  string xmlString = "<Products><Product><Id>1</Id><Name>My XML product</Name><Sexo></Sexo></Product></Products>";

  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>), new XmlRootAttribute("Products"));

  StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);

  List<Product> productList = (List<Product>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

  productList.Dump();

}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public claves_sexo Sexo {get;set;}
}

public enum claves_sexo
{
    HO,
    MU,
    ND
}
```

I would like the Sexo member of Product, to be assigned the value ND = 2 for the enum when it's not informed.

I've been playing with the XmlIgnore attribute and created another member to import the value for the empty tag as a String, and assign it to Sexo member, but I didn't succeeded.

- I've been asked to change the type of the Sexo member to String, but I cannot change the type claves_sexo, as it belongs to some settled standard we use.

FINAL Note: this is the version that finally works:

```
void Main()
{
    string xmlString = "<Products><Product><Id>1</Id><Name>My XML product</Name><Sexo>ND</Sexo></Product></Products>";  
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>), new XmlRootAttribute("Products"));
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
    List<Product> productList = (List<Product>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
    productList.Dump();
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public claves_sexo Sexo {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("Sexo")]
    public string SexoAsString
    {
        get
        {
            return Sexo.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                Sexo = claves_sexo.ND;
            }
            else
            {
                Sexo = (claves_sexo)Enum.Parse(typeof(claves_sexo), value);
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum claves_sexo
{
    HO,
    MU,
    ND
}
```

Thanks to everyone !

Roger

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmldefaultvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: *I've been playing with the XmlIgnore attribute and created another member to import the value for the empty tag as a String, and assign it to Sexo member, but I didn't succeeded* - then can you share the attempt that failed, i.e. a [mcve]?  It should work, see e.g. [XmlSerializer enumeration deserialization failing on (non existent) whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4526887) -- assuming your setter checks for an incoming empty string of course.

Comment: Does setting `ND = 0` in the enum def helps?

Comment: @Aybe - adding `[DefaultValue(claves_sexo.ND)]` to `Sexo` doesn't seem to help, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/oDNFK5

Comment: Adding a surrogate string property totally works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/zaJR9a.  Not sure where your problem is.

Comment: use  enum with Description attributes like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value)

Comment: Definitely not the best approach to take, you can consider doing some pre-processing on the xml before passing it to the serializer, like `.Replace("<Sexo></Sexo>", "<Sexo>ND</Sexo>")`.

Comment: @dbc Thanks ! yours is the correct answer ! I was putting the incorrect attribute in (from your dotnetfiddle) SexoSurrogate member, it had to be [XmlElement("Sexo")] instead of that [XmlAttribute] I was using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`XmlEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) attribute:

```
public enum claves_sexo
{
    [XmlEnum("HO")]HO,
    [XmlEnum("MU")]MU,
    [XmlEnum("")]ND
}
```

EDIT: You can use multiple names with the same value to handle both "" and "ND":

```
public enum claves_sexo
{
    [XmlEnum("HO")]HO,
    [XmlEnum("MU")]MU,
    [XmlEnum("ND")]ND,
    [XmlEnum("")]Default = ND,
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works if the xml comes with an empty tag, thanks. But if it comes with <sexo>ND</sexo>, it fails. What can I do to assign ND when the value comes empty OR "ND" ?

Comment: thanks this works ! it's simpler, I like it. Can you explain us where that "Default" property comes from ? I cannot find any online documentation referring to this property. It's clear what it means, and how it works, yes, but where is it documented ? If you could please tell us the link ... And I think the "= 2" is redundant, as the code works without it (the real value of ND is 2, as this is the natural order in which this member appears on the enumeration)

Comment: @Roger `= 2` is indeed redundant, it was a leftover from testing. `Default`(with a capital D) is not anything special, just a name like `HO` or `MU`. In an enum, you can multiple name with the same value. Here, `Default` has the value of `ND`, so they are the same when you compare them. Except when you `.ToString()` or format them, the first name will be printed. However, who is the first is left to the compiler to decide.